# jQuery - Radio button state change

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I've been digging into both `.attr()` and `.prop()`, but having quite a bit of trouble getting a radio select option to work.

The basic premise is I have two radio buttons, one is selected by default. When a different radio button is selected, it should show a slew of divs that have the class it calls with `.show()`. I had it working partially, but when you would select that same radio button that was already selected, it would run the `.show()` action again - so I tried to add in a check to see if 'checked' was defined or not, but it's not meshing. My brain is about at its breaking point, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also - I'm sure there's a more efficient way to write this, so using jQuery 1.7.1 if there is... please :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if (jQuery('#section-of_homepage_display input[value="slideshow"]:checked').val() === undefined) {
        jQuery('#section-of_homepage_display input[value="slideshow"]').click(function() {
            jQuery('.homepage_display').hide(400);
            jQuery('.homepage_display_slides').show(400);
        });
    }

    if (jQuery('#section-of_homepage_display input[value="slideshow"]:checked').val() !== undefined) {
        jQuery('.homepage_display_slides').show();
    }

    if (jQuery('#section-of_homepage_display input[value="static"]:checked').val() === undefined) {
        jQuery('#section-of_homepage_display input[value="static"]').click(function() {
            jQuery('.homepage_display').hide(400);
            jQuery('.homepage_display_static').show(400);
        });
    }

    if (jQuery('#section-of_homepage_display input[value="static"]:checked').val() !== undefined) {
        jQuery('.homepage_display_static').show();
    }

});
```

Comment: Look for .attr('checked') == 'checked'

Comment: Hi @Diodeus appreciate the response. Now have http://jsfiddle.net/MMVgp/ but the initial check for if the radio button is checked or not is still not working. Also, only running the `.click()` function if the radio button is not checked doesn't seem to be working either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jessegavin/8ByKA/2/

```
jQuery(function() {

    // This function handles the radio clicks.
    function handleSelection() {
        var duration = 400;
        jQuery('.homepage_display').hide(duration);
        if (this.value === "slideshow") {
          jQuery('.homepage_display_slides').show(duration);     
        } else if (this.value === "static") {
          jQuery('.homepage_display_static').show(duration);     
        }
    }

    // Hide all elements initially
    // To prevent showing the non-selected items at first
    jQuery('.homepage_display').hide();

    // Attach a click handler to the radios
    // and trigger the selected radio
    jQuery("#section-of_homepage_display :radio")
        .click(handleSelection)
        .filter(":checked").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Hi @jessegavin thank you very much for the response! This seems to be working great except for when a radio option is already selected, you can still click it and the `.show()` duration still fires (so it basically collapses and re-opens). Is there anyway to check if the radio button is selected or not and only run the `.show()` function based on that? Definitely a lot more efficient than my previous code though :) Thanks!